# Unable to access Windows share

Tags: linux, windows, alfresco

I've installed Alfresco 4.2.d under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS; Everything done fine except I can't access it from Windows share (Windows 7 32bit) although I got the link from Alfresco explorer which is:

```
file:///%5C%5CECSA%5CAlfresco%5CSites%5Cswsdp%5CdocumentLibrary%5CAgency%20Files%5CImages%5Ccoins.JPG
```

I tried to access it from: **\\ECSA** but I failed too so I made a ping (192.168.0.70 is server IP) then I got:

```
C:\Users\user>ping 192.168.0.70

Pinging 192.168.0.70 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.70: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.70: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.70: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.70: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.70:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\Users\user>ping ECSA
Ping request could not find host ECSA. Please check the name and try

C:\Users\user>
```

Some logs of what's going on:

```
C:\Users\user>net view ECSA
System error 1707 has occurred.

The network address is invalid.


C:\Users\user>nbtstat -a 192.168.0.70

Local Area Connection:
Node IpAddress: [192.168.0.84] Scope Id: []

           NetBIOS Remote Machine Name Table

       Name               Type         Status
    ---------------------------------------------
    ECSA           <20>  UNIQUE      Registered
    ECSA           <00>  UNIQUE      Registered
    WORKGROUP      <00>  GROUP       Registered

    MAC Address = 00-00-00-00-00-00


C:\Users\user>
```

CIFS Server Configuration in file-servers.properties

```
### CIFS Server Configuration - file-servers.properties ###
cifs.enabled=true
cifs.serverName=${localname}A
cifs.domain=
cifs.broadcast=255.255.255.255
cifs.bindto=192.168.0.70
cifs.ipv6.enabled=false
cifs.hostannounce=true
cifs.disableNIO=false
cifs.disableNativeCode=false
cifs.sessionTimeout=900
cifs.maximumVirtualCircuitsPerSession=16
cifs.tcpipSMB.port=445
cifs.netBIOSSMB.sessionPort=139
cifs.netBIOSSMB.namePort=137
cifs.netBIOSSMB.datagramPort=138
cifs.WINS.autoDetectEnabled=true
cifs.WINS.primary=192.168.0.70
cifs.WINS.secondary=192.168.0.1
cifs.sessionDebug=
cifs.pseudoFiles.enabled=true
cifs.pseudoFiles.explorerURL.enabled=true
cifs.pseudoFiles.explorerURL.fileName=__Alfresco.url
cifs.pseudoFiles.shareURL.enabled=false
cifs.pseudoFiles.shareURL.fileName=__Share.url
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What happens if you try to access it as \\\(server ip address) instead of \\\(server name) ?

Comment: I think it should be `net view \\ECSA`.

Comment: @Gagravarr it asks me for username and password; when I input them it fails!!!

Comment: That's a good start! You'll need to give you Alfresco credentials, and ensure that those credentials are from a part of the auth chain that is CIFS compatible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew how to fix this issue; It's not related to Alfresco at all :( I discover it when I used another Windows PC with same network configurations.

All what I did to fix it is creating a new Windows user with administration privileges then deleted the old one... Voila it works.

thank you guys for help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the computer name of windows machines is exchanged with the NetBIOS protocol, which is unknown by the regular linux utilities such as ping, etc. If you want to use it on Linux, you will have to set it up in your DNS records, or in your host file (typically `/etc/hosts`).

Comment: I don't want to use it under Linux. Alfresco installed under Linux but the users will use it under Windows through CIFS

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty basic stuff.

```
Ping request could not find host ECSA. Please check the name and try
```

The client can't resolve the name of the computer hosting the share. You need to provide a name resolution mechanism for the clients. DNS, Hosts file, etc.

Comment: No this isn't a basic thing! because when I added 192.168.0.70 to WINS address I could ping ecsa